# A splitter for low-voltage wire

Tags: wiring

I want to run some low-voltage wire in my yard for path/accent lighting.  I want to avoid connecting everything to a single segment of wire, mainly to reduce power loss associated with long runs.

So instead, I want to run a trunk wire, with branches splitting away from it.  I plan for the wire to be 12-gauge copper.

What's a suitable splitter for this purpose?  Ideally this splitter would also have a quick-disconnect functionality, but that's optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct burial connectors.

Several varieties exist, silicone packed and grease packed are the most common.

You cut and strip and twist the connection(s) and insert into the cap, which then isolates, insulates and waterproofs the connection.

They are a HUGE step up from the "vampire tap" connections that come with low priced landscape sets.  In any type of wet climate, the taps are only good for several years

[image]

Another approach is a "staked" junction box. which houses the connections for a hub distribution method.  The junction box sits atop a ground stake, keeping the wiring above ground.

[image]